# What is the prefered way of clearing floated content?

Tags: css

I am wondering what is the prefered way of escaping floats nowadays.

I have usually added a div with clear: both property after the floaters but there are many more.

I would like to know what is the clean solution usually prefered by professional developers?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, if it works and is simple, stick with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually use `overflow: hidden` on the element containing the floated elements, and for the times that I need `overflow` to be set to something other than `hidden`, I use the `.clearfix` class as mentioned by @Lapple.

Comment: @Lapple Ha, sorry. Resolution is getting too small or I'm getting too old.

Comment: I will choose this as best since I knew this method and how good and clean it was. I will start to use it - always thought there are some issues with it.

Comment: @HNikolas Just issues if you want overflow to be visible, scroll, or something other than hidden.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `.clearfix` magic, used in [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://h5bp.com):

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { zoom: 1; }
```

And you can probably start using `display: inline-block` nowadays, or not?